# Java and Azure functions Declarative settings for multiple environments dev/test/prod

Tags: java, azure

So
We are planning to use Azure Functions to connect to Azure Service Bus and trigger on Topics (the question however applies basically to all azure parts)

MS has created Java Libs and code that use Annotations that one applies to the code.

```
@FunctionName("sbtopicprocessor")
public void run(
        @ServiceBusTopicTrigger(
                name = "message",
                topicName = "topic",
                subscriptionName = "mysubscription",
                connection = "ServiceBusConnection"
        ) String message,
        final ExecutionContext context
) {
    context.getLogger().info(message);
}
```

The problem is to get these annotation to be set at runtime.
This is not supported by Java and this makes injecting values
at runtime impossible.

How should i go about this to avoid having different code for the different environments?

The only way i have found so far is to actually have ALL topics active on ALL environments.

p.s.
I would like to avoid using Spring as we are a Jakarta team.
d.s.

Comment: You can set environment variables for each environment and use them in your code. For example, you can set an environment variable for the connection string and use it in your code. Check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-java?tabs=bash%2Cconsumption) it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Configuration without hardcoding values using Jakarta EE Config in a Jakarta EE application.

- Create an interface for your configuration properties, such as `MyConfig.java`. This interface defines the properties you want to configure.

```
import org.eclipse.microprofile.config.inject.ConfigProperty;

public interface MyConfig {
    @ConfigProperty(name = "my.property")
    String myProperty();
}
```

You can access your environmental variables like this below. check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-java?tabs=bash%2Cconsumption#environment-variables).

[image]

- Create property files for each environment you want to support. For example, I have created two property files as `application-dev.properties` and `application-prod.properties`.

[image]

Inject the configuration properties:

```java
import javax.inject.Inject;

public class MyService {
    @Inject
    private MyConfig myConfig;

    public String getMyProperty() {
        return myConfig.myProperty();
    }
}
```

Jakarta EE application can dynamically switch configurations by changing the environment-specific property files or by modifying the active profile.

Comment: Well as the values in the annotation are set (only) at compiletime that really does not help?

In the example you show you can see the string "req" that is what i need to set  at runtime.

But thank you anyway, or did i misunderstand?